# How to enable USB android tethering on OS X Mountain Lion without using Easy-Tether (Lite)

Tags: macos, network, usb, android

I can tether fine to Windows 7, but on my Mac OS X Mountain Lion, it does not recognize the USB network.  I can install Easy-Tether (Lite) but that comes with some restrictions (e.g. no secure web pages, so no gmail), so I'd like to use the built in tethering of Cyanogenmod 7 that I have on my Android phone.

Is there anyway to fix the Mac OS X Mountain Lion install so that it properly recognizes the USB network connection?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the device with tethering enabled and opening the Network preference pane? Sometimes you need to add a new network connection for the OS to see third party devices that don't get automagically recognized. Also, if you can explain the protocol the mod speaks - perhaps we can dig up a kext or configuration script for you.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this, but there is no choice for USB network, only choices are: Wi-Fi, BlueTooth PAN, BlueTooth DUN, VPN, PPPoE, and 6 to 4.

Comment: Bummer - that was the easy way out. Perhaps these nice folk would have a better answer for you? http://android.stackexchange.com - They might at least know the protocol your phone speaks and that could be added here in case it improves the details in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this isn't your preference, but the [paid version of Easy Tether](http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/android.html) comes with the appropriate Mac OS X kernel extensions - so you could just pay the one time fee (currently $10) to have this feature programmed by someone who has done the work.

I'm fine with you not selecting this answer, but wanted it here for others that might need a solution that gets around the restrictions in the Lite version of the tethering software.

Comment: I just don't understand why the operating system doesn't include this already like it does on Windows.

Comment: The OS detects iOS tethering over USB with no drivers needed, so I don't know if android is doing something non-standard or if there is no standard or OS X is missing some drivers that windows has made. You might ask on http://superuser.com/ what makes the Windows OS work with that tethering. I do know that Mac OS doesn't add things unless there is a good reason to change the core OS. Perhaps adding a subsystem that would be used by few people was put on a shelf until Android becomes more popular with Mac users.